# How to avoid this looping when try to reach index()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, pyrocms, ion-auth

I'm trying to check if `$this->current_user` is set, otherwise redirect to the login page but because Wall is my default route it loops and give me a **500 Internal Server Error**, does any have some ideas in how to work with that? I'm using [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com) and them use [IonAuth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/).

```
class Wall extends Public_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    if (empty($this->current_user)) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Debes iniciar sesión para acceder a esta página');
         redirect(site_url());
     }
    }

 }
```

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: umm... redirect somewhere else? What's the issue here?

Comment: @orourkek Wall is defined as my default controller so any times the app try to reach the index() without login it executes the  __construct before any else and for that the loop and redirect to somewhere else isn't an option because break the entire application logic

Comment: Well you said you were redirecting to `/login`, but you just had `site_url()` as the redirect parameter. You literally answered the question *within the question*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect() method redirects to a URL. You can use redirect(site_url('login')); as long as you make sure that you have a controller ready with the name 'login'.

If you don't want to use site_url(), you can also hardcode the URL in like:

redirect('http://www.yoursite.com/login');

Comment: thanks didn't think on that before! It works by now I redirect directly to the login form